# Validation of Date is not working

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I tried the following code earlier and it worked fine ,but now its not able to validate the date based on the format given.

```
 NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *validateDOB = [format dateFromString:textField.text];
if (validateDOB != nil)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
```

When i am trying to validate date string as 24-12-199 , the validateDOB is returning the value as "0199-12-23 18:06:32 +0000"

Comment: Set `locale` and `time zone` properties of date formatted.

Comment: what teh problem u faced

Comment: check your year is wrong `199` it is `1999`

Comment: date always returns with zones

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you have printed `0199-12-23 18:06:32 +0000` this from debug console.

Please see this : `+0000` at End. As NSDate object always saves data in +0000 timezone. But when you print it by converting it into string, it will automatically takes your current time zone in account and will print the date. So, dont worry about it, the saved date is perfectly fine

NSDate is always saved in GMT time, but the NSDateFormatter adds the twist by adding current time zone into it. So you can change the timezone if you want.

Comment: "it will automatically takes your current time zone in account and will print the date".  No it won't!  It's prints in GMT (given `NSDate` doesn't store a timezone).

Comment: Now do one thing.. convert that NSDate again back to NSString by using same date formatter.. are you getting same date as you saved or are you gettting GMT's Date. I am 100% sure that it will print your own date.

Comment: The reason is, NSDate always saved in GMT, it doesnt have timezone, but NSDateFormatter has timezone property, which converts it back to your current time zone

Comment: You state in your answer than using `NSLog()` to print the date will print it using your current time zone.  That is not true.  It will call `[NSDate description]` and that will print the date in GMT (i.e. no timezone).

Comment: my point is that, why i am getting the value of validateDOB as 0199 for year. as only 199 was entered to check for date validation for the yyyy format.

Comment: if year entered is 199 then the value for validateDOB should be nil